# Change default HTSQL output format

Tags: htsql

I need to set my HTSQL server to act as a JSON API server, returning JSON-formatted output by default, not only when a query is followed by `/:json`.  Is there a way to do this?

Reason: I need to send queries that are formulated by software that automatically places parameters (`?foo='bar'&baz='moo'`) at the *end* of the URL, but HTSQL only recognizes an output format specifier like `/:json` when *it* comes at the absolute end of the URL, *after* the parameters.  I don't know a way to build URLs like that without tedious and error-prone direct manipulation of the entire URL.

In other words, HTSQL demands that URLS look like

```
/mytable?col1='val1'&col2='val2'/:json
```

but I can't put the `/:json` after the parameters, so I'm looking for a way to have `/:json` be automatically implied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to submit the desired format with the `Accept` HTTP header.  For example, `Accept: x-htsql/json` should give you JSON output.

You can also change the default output format, but it's rather tedious: You need to create an HTSQL addon and override `htsql.core.fmt.emit.EmitDefault` extension.  Perhaps, you can bypass creating an addon by hot-patching this class.